# Symfony 3.4 - The EntityManager is closed

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I have an application run with Symfony 3.4 with MySql and I get a error: 'The EntityManager is closed'. My application running two ways:

1 - A Console application thats is called by a sh script every time. This console app make many inserts in a database table.

2 - A HTTP Route that also insert in same table.

When de console app is running in background if i call the http route i get the error 'The EntityManager is closed'. If I stop de backgroud app the http route works. It's as if the two apps console and http use the same instance EntityManager.

My code:

I Create a service called AbstractRepositoryService. All of my services that manage repositories should extend.

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractRepositoryService
{

    /**
     *  
     * @var EntityManagerIntergace - $em
    */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * 
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
    */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {

        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     *
     * 
     * @param String
     * 
     * @return @mixed
     * 
     * @throws RuntimeException
    */
    public function __call($method, $args) {

        $repository = $this->em->getRepository(static::ENTITY);

        if (!method_exists($repository, $method)) {

            throw new RuntimeException(
                sprintf("Method '%s' not found.", $method), 
                500
            );
        }

        try {

            return call_user_func_array(array($repository, $method), $args);

        } catch(Exception $e) {

            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }

    }
}
```

My UserRepositoryService where the exception is thrown in the **flush method**

```
<?php

final class UserRepositoryService extends AbstractRepositoryService
{
    /**
     * 
     * @const String
    */
    const ENTITY = 'AppBundle\\Entity\\User';

    /**
     * 
     * @param User
    */
    public function insert(User $user) {

        try {

            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush($user);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly my service declaration:

```
app.services.user_repository_service:
        public: true
        class: AppBundle\Services\UserRepositoryService
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

Comment: What is the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. The error I get is: The EntityManager is closed.

Comment: Yes, I see. But what is the question. I don't see any ;)

Comment: Throwing an exception will cause the entity manager to close though it's not clear to me if that is happening in your code.  Just my opinion but it seems just a bit convoluted.  I might add that normally you would use a factory service to create repositories though I guess you are trying to decouple your repositories from Doctrine repositories.

Comment: The question is why do I get the error when I run the console application and http at the same time. If I stop the console and run only http the error does not happen.

Comment: Im guessin its probaby because when the script is working the entity manager from the script locks table for a time it inserts data and any other connection from other EM fails. Try to manually insert any data in the table when the script is working and see if you are able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

I created a method that generate new EntityManager before insert and works now.

```
protected function createNewEntityManager() {

    return $this->em->create(
        $this->em->getConnection(),
        $this->em->getConfiguration(),
        $this->em->getEventManager()
    );
}
```

And in insert:

```
public function insert(Crawler $crawler) {

    try {

        $this->createNewEntityManager();

        $this->em->persist($crawler);
        $this->em->flush($crawler);
        $this->em->close();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: createNewEntityManager returns a value but it is not assigned when called at insert method.

Comment: This answer worked for me. But for make this solution work, you have to use the returned value of createNewEntityManager Something like this `$this->em = $this->createNewEntityManager();`.